# Can the Eclipse formatter for Java be configured to put right parenthesis of function call to new line if wrapped?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

Can the Eclipse formatter and/or code cleanup for Java be configured (or extended) to add a new line before the right parenthesis of a function/method invocation? Up to now I managed to format the code like the following:

```
// some code here
foo.aVeryLongMethodNameWhichCausesLineWraps(
    param1,
    param2);
// and some other code here
```

But what I'd like to have is the following:

```
// some code here
foo.aVeryLongMethodNameWhichCausesLineWraps(
    param1,
    param2
);
// and some other code here
```

For nested invocations it should look like the following:

```
// some code here
foo.bar(
    nested(
        param1,
        param2
    )
);
// and some other code here
```

Is this possible? If not, is there any chance to extend the formatter to provide such feature?

Comment: Close-vote reviewers: this question is on-topic because "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.**" That is clearly the case here.

Answer (score 0):

But you see, why it's a not that obvious idea?
How would it behave for methods without parameters?

`foo.aVeryLongMethodNameWhichCausesLineWraps(
);`

It doesn't look that good, does it?
There are of course pros and cons for each code formatting, but if you use not that good API of some guy from your office and that guy wanted to have 10 parameters in his methods it would mean that you'd have something like this:

`foo.bar(
    nested(
        param1,
        param2,
        param3,
        param4,
        param5,
        param6,
        param7,
        param8,
        param9
    ),
    param1,
    param2,
    param3,
    param4,
    param5,
    param6,
    param7,
    param8,
    param9
);`
You can ease your pain of improper formatting by using Editbox plugin:

http://editbox.sourceforge.net

Comment: What you suggest as bad example is exactly the behavior I'm looking for.
It eases code diffing and review.
Addition, removal, and modification of parameters are very easy to track with this formatting.